# RequiredFieldValidation not working properly for listbox

Tags: asp.net, listbox, requiredfieldvalidator, client-side-validation

I have a listbox on my asp.net page for which I have used rquiredfieldvalidation.
The problem is when the list box is filled on a particular dropdown selection ,no member is automatically selected in that case.On save click it is treated as empty and the validation still shows.

Only when **I explicitly select one member** does the validation go and I am able to save.

I tried using javascript function to select first member automatically on OnCLientClick of my Save button.But there the problem is that when I move members from another listbox to this listbox,already a member is selected.After that my function call selects another member.Thus two are selected and in that case it is erroring out.

Here is the javascript function used:

```
function FunSelect()
{
            var objRequiredFunctionalities = document
                .getElementById("<%=lbCurrentFunc.ClientID%>");

            if (objRequiredFunctionalities.selectedIndex > 0 ||      
                     objRequiredFunctionalities.options.length > 0) {
                objRequiredFunctionalities.options[0].selected = true;
            }
        }
```

This is the code for moving items from one listbox to the listbox for which I have the validation

```
    function ShiftToRight() {
        var objSource = document.getElementById("<%=lbAllFunc.ClientID%>");
        var objRequiredFunctionalities = document.getElementById("<%=lbCurrentFunc.ClientID%>");

        if (objSource.selectedIndex < 0 || objSource.options.length < 0) {
            alert("Select Item in Left List to move.");
            return;
        }
        var flag = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < objSource.options.length; i++) {
            if (objSource.options[i].selected) {
                var item = objSource.options[i];
                i--;
                for (var i = 0; i < objRequiredFunctionalities.options.length; i++) {
                    if (item.value == objRequiredFunctionalities.options[i].value)
                        flag = 1;
                }
                if (flag == 0) {
                    if (navigator.appName == 'Netscape') {
                        objRequiredFunctionalities.options.add(item);
                    }
                    else {
                        objRequiredFunctionalities.options.appendChild(item);
                    }
                }
                else alert("Selected item already exists in the Current Functionalities");

            }
        }
```

Comment: How are you moving members? Can't you unselect while moving the items?

Comment: @nunespascal Please see the edited question for the code for moving items.Can you now suggest something?

Answer (score 0):

Cuisine Type:

```
      <asp:RequiredFieldValidator ID="CuisineTypeReqFieldValid" InitialValue="-1" Display="dynamic" runat="server" ControlToValidate="CuisineType">
      <div class="SearchFormRow">
        <span class="SearchFormRowLabel">&nbsp;</span>
        <span class="SearchFormRowField">You must select at least 1 item from the list!</span>
      </div>
      </asp:RequiredFieldValidator>
```